# What is the salary range for a Post Doc in France?

Tags: postdocs, engineering, france

I was wondering what is the salary range for a Post Doc in France (Engineering - Ecole des Mines)?

In the UK the range is £31K - 38K and I'm already midway in the range. I'm considering moving to France for an interesting Post Doc and I was wondering how much of a salary I can negotiate.

Comment: what do they advertise?

Comment: from 2100 Euros per month but not the range. I don't want to negotiate until I have a solid offer but I need to know whats the range so I can make a reasonable demand based on my current salary grade. I know I need to take a pay cut in France but I'd like to minimise it.

Comment: You need to compare the tax situations, insurances etc as well - it's not just the total paid...

Comment: I doubt it will be more than 2300 per month net (times 12). Cost of living in Paris can be very high.

Comment: Be careful of what kind of salary you're talking about and reading about – in France, the difference between gross salary (before social security deductions) and net salary (what will end up in your bank account) can be as high as 2x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did two post-doc in France, both paid by public institutions.

- In 2013, [CNRS](http://www.cnrs.fr/) paid 2.022€ net per month,
- In 2014, [INRIA](https://www.inria.fr/) paid 2.120€ net per month.

This included social security, but I had to pay some taxes at the end of the year (so beware and save!).

I also had access to various benefits, both from my employer, e.g.,

- re-allocation funds,
- contributing to the cost of my commuting (this is a legal obligation, and they will happily comply),
- financial help to pay a nurse for my kid

and from the state.

**Those offers were "forfait" and not negotiable.**
Most of the public employers will be happy to provide you with additional information about the various benefits you can access to, and to discuss the cost of living, but **they have absolutely no room to discuss your salary.**

If you look at the [INRIA's webpage](https://www.inria.fr/en/institute/recruitment/offers/post-doctoral-research-fellowships/faq#section7), they explicitly give the salary for a post-doc with them: there won't be no exception, everyone gets the same salary, no matter the town, subject, experience, qualification, PI, etc.

I don't know precisely the situation at *L'école des Mines*, but I would be surprised if the situation was much different. [This page](http://www.mines-paristech.fr/Ecole/Recrutement/Travailler-a-MINES-ParisTech/) reads

> Pour ses actions de recherche et afin de conforter les liens très
>   forts qu’elle entretient avec les entreprises françaises et
>   étrangères, l’École recrute également de jeunes scientifiques,
>   titulaires d’un doctorat ou d’un diplôme équivalent,
>
> - sur contrat à durée déterminée, éventuellement renouvelable
> - leur assure une rémunération brute mensuelle allant de 2 340 € à 2 944 €.(chiffre 2007)
> - leur permet d’acquérir au sein de ses laboratoires de l’École une expérience complémentaire de très haut niveau dans les métiers de la
>     recherche

So, in 2007, the salary range for a post doc was between 2.340€ and 2.944€ but I would assume that on what ends of that spectrum you land depends on your age, experience, social status, and **not** on negotiation. I could be wrong: the better way to get a definitive answer is to ask them!

Comment: it is also crucial to note that this salary is paid 12 times/year. In other countries (NL, Austria for example) it is paid 14 times. The commute cost is not paid in full (in paris I was paid only 40%)

Comment: Yes. Employment in France, especially public employment, is very very regulated in terms of salary, with fixed rates that are calculated based on specific factors such as what degree you hold and how long you have been in the job. (I remember getting an automatic raise for completing my B.Sc.) I wouldn't expect there to be any room for negotiating at all.

Comment: Note that you can use [this simulator](https://www3.impots.gouv.fr/simulateur/calcul_impot/2017/index.htm) for how much taxes you are going to pay. It's in French, but the tax administration is only going to communicate with you in French, so you better get used to it... Indicatively, in 2017 a net salary of 2100€/mo gives a yearly tax amount of 1816€, for a single person with no kids with no other revenue and no applicable deductions. Of course this can vary a lot depending on your precise situation.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Also, the Taxe d'Habitation should be included in that. Most landlords ask the tennat to pay for it. It can be quite high.

Comment: @PsySp Uh, the State asks the tenants to pay for it. It's a tax for tenants, not landlords (its name literally means "tenant tax"). The owner pays a separate tax called "taxe foncière" (in addition to income tax on the revenue generated by the rent). If you own your own home, you pay both. However this tax will be reduced next year and disappear for 80% of the population in 2020 (as a postdoc you're definitely in the 80% of least rich people).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Depends. I was renting an apartment and was not asked to pay for it. In any case this is a tax that someone going to france should be aware

Comment: @PsySp Your sentence is ambiguous. Are you renting the apartment in the sense that you are paying the owner to live there, or are you the owner and renting the apartment to someone else? In the first case, if you were living in the apartment on January 1st (that's how it works), then you did have to pay the tax (and I don't know how you managed to evade it). In the second case, you didn't, the tenant did.

Comment: Okay, you deleted and posted another comment that literally says the opposite, so I don't know what to tell you. Let met clarify: the physical person living in the apartment on January 1st has to pay the tax. It's as simple as that. The landlord shouldn't even be involved in that, it's between the tenant and the tax administration. It's possible that you were being scammed by a landlord who wanted you to pay the tax when you didn't (because if the apartment is empty two years in a row, then the landlord has to pay a special tax in some cities).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry for the confusion. The point is that on one occasion I was _not_ asked to pay for it (I do not know how, I guess was part of the rent?). The second point is that this tax can be quite high (I do not know if they will cancel it or what) so a PostDoc with 2200 eu times 12 should be aware that has to pay something as high as 700-1000 eu

Comment: Thank you all for all of the information. I'm quite young (in relation to having a PhD), with a few years of experience. Lets see what I am offered. I will do 1 month training at my hosting institution and then I will be 'sold' to a company to conduct research on site for 14 months. The area is fairly cheap and away from Paris. Good opportunity to work on my horrific French.
So I will Pay:
Income tax
National Insurance (health/pension...)
Council Tax (for the apartment)
Which is the same as the UK with the exception they ask for their money at the end of the year. Anything else missed?

Comment: @SaeidAlami Health insurance and pension savings are automatically already deducted from your paycheck (when you are given the "net" salary, it's taken into account). However you will probably also need to take out [mutual insurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_insurance), which is in addition to the national basic health insurance and has greater coverage and more reimbursement. It's not extremely expensive though (at the most, 500€/year given your postdoc salary I think, paid out monthly usually).

Comment: @SaeidAlami I believe the discussion on the break of your salary, how much you need, etc., should be addressed at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ or using tools like https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/, but can't really be addressed in comments. I understand how this is connected to your original question, but it it not part of your original question, and probably off-topic for academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just as an update, in 2021, a postdoc with 2 years experience can be paid in astronomy  3200 € "net" / month (i.e. what comes on their bank account after tax).

Comment: @chris Who's your employer?

Comment: @Clément CNRS (well both my employer and that of the postdoc)

Comment: @chris How much was this before taxes? Was your salary also "forfait" (non-negotiable)? Was your salary automatically incremented year to year?

Comment: @Clément I don't know. There is sometimes some level of negociation at the level of 15% in our case. The salary is incremented each year.

Comment: @chris Out of curiosity, who is the employer?

Comment: The employer is CNRS